# How to extract data from a ned-red flow

Tags: node-red

I have 4 flows
serial flow for my Arduino
JSON flow to format my data in JSON format
function flow to extract the data from my dht11 sensor
and finally debug flow
first i will show you the configuration of my flows
[image: my flows]

my function :
[image: json flow]

my sql database

[image: sql database]

the error message

[image: error]

my JSON flow

[image: json flow]

the output

[image: data]

help me please I thought that I will have had something like this in my database

```
"INSERT INTO sensordata (temperature,humidite) VALUES(20, 30);";
```

but i have

```
mysql> select *from sensordata ;
+--------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| idData | humidite  | temperature | dateSensor          |
+--------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|   2471 | undefined | undefined   | 2021-01-01 16:24:23 |
|   2472 | undefined | undefined   | 2021-01-01 16:24:24 |
+--------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: We need to see the output of the `JSON` node to be able to help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what the input to the function node is I will have to guess.

It looks like you are trying to access fields which don't exist on the `msg` object but can probably be found a level deeper in the `msg.payload` object.

You can change the function node to:

```
msg.topic = "insert into sensordata(temperature,humidite) values('" + msg.payload.temperature + "','" + msg.payload.humidite + "')"
```

There is no need to attach the values to the `msg` object as extra `payload#`.

Comment: I love you sir you save my life